# Navigate through MLToolkit.Forms.SwipeCardView

Tags: xamarin, swipecardview

I'm developing a Tinder-like app using the MLToolkit.Forms.SwipeCardView nuget.
How do I,

1. Reload the cardView when it reaches the end (or at any time), and start all over again? Using

   SwipeCardView.LoopCards = true;

works, but not exactly what I want.

2. Undo the last swipe action?
3. Navigate forward/backward through the cards stack?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer question no.1 myself. After a few trials, I found a simple method to restart or to refresh the SwipeCardView, at anytime. I thought I'd share it here and hope it helps someone. Just simply rebinding it, like so...

```
swipeCardView1.BindingContext = null;
swipeCardView1.BindingContext = this;
```